# How to print the outcome into points and not a line?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot

Now with this code it prints out a line how to print how a line made out of points?

```
def f(x):
   return

a=[(x,f(x)) for x in range(-100,100)]

# Plotting the values 
plt.plot(*zip(*a))
plt.show()
```

Comment: `def f(x):` should do something... think you missed to return. You can change `plt.plot()` to `plt.scatter()` to show points instead. Read up on [scatter plots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) to see options

Comment: Change this line `plt.plot(*zip(*a), 'o')`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, @bn_ln answer works perfectly. however, if you wanted to use the 'scatter' method for any reason you could do it like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return x**2

a = [(x,f(x)) for x in range(-100,100, 10)]

plt.scatter(*list(zip(*a)))
plt.show()
```

or

```
plt.scatter(
    x=list(zip(*a))[0],
    y=list(zip(*a))[1],
)
plt.show()
```

[image]